# Code Generation for SOAP Requests (UPNP)

Tags: c#, soap, windows-runtime, code-generation, upnp

I am trying to control a UPnP device that accepts commands through SOAP requests. I found a lot of frameworks and or libraries for .NET but I am targeting Windows Store and am limited to WinRT/.NETcore.

The available commands are published through XML files which describe the parameters/outputs etc. Example: http://pastie.org/private/edlnm4a8hpcrwwsbbwgywg

I was able to manually forge a SOAP request to execute a command (in this case pause):

Headers:

```
POST /MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control HTTP/1.1
CONNECTION: close
ACCEPT-ENCODING: gzip
HOST: 1.1.1.1:1400
CONTENT-LENGTH: 252
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#Pause"
```

Body

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:Pause xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID></u:Pause></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

What I am looking for:

1. A possibility to auto-generate classes off the description XML files (basically what happens when adding a service reference
2. A way to issue these SOAP requests (basically like with a web service which is added as service reference) without having to fiddle with every single request/header etc.

Thanks!

Comment: [ohNet](http://www.openhome.org/wiki/OhNet) has code to autogenerate C# classes (which handle all SOAP communication) from UPnP service descriptions.  There aren't builds available for WinRT but I have no reason to believe it wouldn't work. I maintain the library and would be happy to help if you have a go with WinRT and find any problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for offering your help. I had a look at your project and it looks quite promising. I am still not sure if it would compile for WinRT but I am not very experienced with coding so this will take a while to figure out. I see that your lib has a large number of classes/methods, could you point me in the right direction where I'd have to look for the code generation? For any further issues I'd get back to you in the ohNet forums.

Comment: See OhNet.mak for build commands on Windows and Generated\Proxies.mak for how to generate code.  Questions either here or on the OpenHome forums will be answered.